# How to reflash Htc Desire 628 properly?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, htc-desire

I tried to reflash my Htc Desire 628 using fastboot, but got following log:

```
PS D:\platform-tools> fastboot oem rebootRUU
OKAY [  0.042s]
Finished. Total time: 0.043s
PS D:\platform-tools> fastboot flash zip firm.zip
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
error: write_sparse_skip_chunk: don't care size 915918919 is not a multiple of the block size 4096
error: write_sparse_skip_chunk: don't care size 115920967 is not a multiple of the block size 4096
Sending sparse 'zip' 1/3 (781249 KB)               error: write_sparse_skip_chunk: don't care size 915918919 is not a multiple of the block size 4096
error: write_sparse_skip_chunk: don't care size 915918919 is not a multiple of the block size 4096
OKAY [ 36.254s]
Writing 'zip'                                      (bootloader) HOSD CL#788931
(bootloader) ERR lzipv2_init : Cannot open file /dev/fastboot_download_U
(bootloader) aJ4Bc
(bootloader) ERR [SD_UPDATE_ERR] update_fb_ZIP_buf: can not find ZIP hea
(bootloader) der
(bootloader) ERR [SD_UPDATE_ERR] sddownload failed: 22
(bootloader) ERR Update zip file failed.
(bootloader) ERR ZIP ERROR, exit read zip loop
(bootloader) ERR ZIP signature checking failed...
(bootloader) Update zip file OK
(bootloader) ERR ZIP ERROR CODE, 22
(bootloader) end@Done
FAILED (remote: '22: fail to flash via downloadzip')
fastboot: error: Command failed
PS D:\platform-tools> fastboot reboot
Rebooting                                          OKAY [  0.001s]
Finished. Total time: 0.008s
```

I took `2PVGIMG_V36BML_UHL_L51_DESIRE_SENSE70_HTC_Europe_1.16.401.1_Radio_0.1524V28P45.0504.0422_1_release_483251_signed_2_4_masud.zip`

firmware from there:
http://forum.gsmdevelopers.com/htc-firmware-unified/11239-htc-desire-628-2pvgimg-v36bml-official-stock-roms-18-03-2017-updated.html

in download mode:

```
*** UNLOCKED ***
htc_v36bml_uhl PVT S-ON
LK-1.01.0000
RADIO-UNKNOWN
OpenDSP-UNKNOWN
OS-1.16.401.1
Aug  2 2016, 19:11:15(788931)
```

bootloader and OEM unlocked, usb debugging enabled, is there something else missing or it is a matter of firmware?

Update:

adb log:

```
PS D:\platform-tools> adb sideload firm.zip
Total xfer: 0.00x
PS D:\platform-tools>
```

in twrp:

```
Updating partition details...
...done
Full SELinux support is present.
MTP Enabled
Starting ADB sideload feature...
Installing zip file '/sideload/package.zip'
Invalid zip file format!
```

Update 2:

```
Updating partition details...
...done
Full SELinux support is present.
MTP Enabled
Installing zip file '/sdcard/firm.zip'
Checking for Digest file...
Skipping Digest check: no Digest file found
Zip file is corrupt!
Error installing zip file '/sdcard/firm.zip'
Updating partition details...
...done
```

Update 3:

```
handle_cota_install: install cwpkg to /ota/cwpg.zip
handle_cota_install: install cwprop to cota/cw.prop
Write host_mode error
handle_cota_install: Can't mount /sdcar, 1 times
handle_cota_install: Can't mount /sdcar, 2 times
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124533/discussion-on-question-by-noname-guy-how-to-reflash-htc-desire-628-properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTC `update.zip` is encrypted and does not respect the standard file layout. META-INF is missing, content is:

```
info.bin
zip_0.zip
zip_1.zip
zip_2.zip
zip_3.zip
zip_4.zip
zip_5.zip
zip_6.zip
```

Therefore this file can only flashed from stock recovery.